# Android programming broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

In my app I have taken two text field like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyWXi.png).  One text field for name like "mr.x" another is purpose like birthday.

I am saving the data name and purpose using broadcast receiver by following code:

```
 public void saveinfo(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("alarmatspecifictime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
         editor.putString("name", nameinput.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("purpose",spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        editor.apply();
        makeText(this, "saved", LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Now I want a notification message using the saved data like `"Today is mr.x Birthday"` from broadcast receiver class.  How can I do it?

Comment: And what exactly is your question? It is not clear.

Comment: i have taken two text field one is name and another is purpose in purpose i have taken some spineer data i am saving the name and purpose in my sharedpreference.now i want to retrived data from broadcastreceiver class and want to use it to  here .setContentText( ). in notification class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are only missing a small piece:

```
String restoredText;
String restoredname;

public void addNotification(Context context) {
    getPref(context);
    String myString = restoredText + " " + restoredname;
    ...
    .setContentText(myString)
    ...
}

public void getPref(Context context) {
    restoredText = sp.getString("purpose", "");
    restoredname = sp.getString("name", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does you want to do here, it's very unclear and also the code you shared doesn't make sense directly.

Still if you are using Spinner then  probably there are more then one items so may be the problem is you are using Share preference to save them all items in "purpose" and "name" keys.

*Sharedpreferences override when data with same key is inserted*. So every time you use sp.putString("name",); previous value will get overwrite and you'll only have the new value.

**For better and correct answer please re-phrase your query an code.**